# How can I use AWS lambda layer by java (Layer is success in Lambda)...error is NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, noclassdeffounderror

I built two project and added layers to AWS Lamba successfully.

And my functions use these two layers.

**This is my structure of layer**

[image: Screen shot]

When I execute the function, an error happened:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I know the location of the layer is inside/opt, 
but how can I use the layer's library in functions?

Answer (score 6):

Anyone trying to figure out how to copy your dependencies (.jar) into `java/lib` directory, this is maven snippet from a project -

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/java/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin></plugins></build>
```

Hope this will come handy to someone

Answer (score 5):

You should locate the files into a folder,  in according to the language:

- Node.js –> nodejs/node_modules or nodejs/node8/node_modules
  (NODE_PATH)
- Python – python -> python/lib/python3.7/site-packages (site
  directories)
- Java –> java/lib (classpath)
- Ruby –> ruby/gems/2.5.0 (GEM_PATH), ruby/lib (RUBY_LIB)
- Or default  All –>  bin (PATH), lib (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

For more details see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

Answer (score 0):

Ashraf's answer is correct, however, if you have custom classes that you also wanted to be included in the jar file, you have to zip the whole fat jar to /java/lib like below

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/java/lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.artifactId}.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Then in your pom.xml, add the plugin and configure this assembly.xml file.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```